# How to edit CSS when it shows spaces between the class name?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to make some styling changes to an already made Wordpress theme. In the store section for example, I want to make the images a little wider. I installed the browser add-on Firebug which lets me hover over the element and it goes straight to the code. So I hover over the image and I see:

```
<img class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image">
```

I keep seeing this when trying to edit CSS. There's space between the class name. Why is that? How do I edit it? I've tried

```
.attachment-shop_catalog{
 (css code)
 }
```

as well as

```
.wp-post-image{
(css code)
}
```

as well as the entire thing

```
.attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image{
(css code)
}
```

and it doesn't make any changes. I'm wondering how I can make changes to this element in the CSS when it shows the class like that.

Comment: The `img` has multiple classes.  `attachment-shop_catalog` is one css `class` and `wp-post-image` is a separate class.

Comment: Your first 2 css blocks use the proper selector... The CSS you put inside those selectors should be affecting the outputted html. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 0):

To specifically edit that combination of classes use `.attachment-shop_catalog.wp-post-image`

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a URL, and the part you are trying to edit? This would help tremendously.

If you are asking:

```
.attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image{
------------------------^ THIS SPACE HERE?
```

2 selectors for that css.

For example:

```
#header.showcase {
    CSS STUFF (EXAMPLE 1)
}

#header .showcase {
    CSS STUFF (EXAMPLE 2)
}
```

Is completely different like this:

```
<div id="header" class="showcase">THIS IS EXAMPLE 1</div>

<div id="header"><div class="showcase">THIS IS EXAMPLE 1</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`attachment-shop_catalog` is a class name. `wp-post-image` is also a class name.

For example you have 2 classes with the same name:

```
<div class="button">Apply</div>
<div class="button">Reset</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.button {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

but you want the button Reset to be smaller. 
In that case you can give to the button Reset a second class name:

```
<div clas="button reset">Reset</div>
```

and make it smaller by using the following CSS:

```
.reset {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

The button will then appear smaller but It'll still have the same style as your apply button.

Hence, you can style the class `attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image` using the following CSS:

```
.wp-post-image {
  ...
}
```

or

```
.attachment-shop_catalog.wp-post-image {
  ...
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2ahQW/)